# How to create apt repository on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, apt, repository, apt-mirror

We have Windows server (1) with Internet access and Windows server (2) without Internet access in PAN. Also we have Linux machines in PAN (Debian, Ubuntu, ...).

Linux machines must be up to date, but there is no Internet access in PAN. How to download updates to server (1) from official mirrors? Then it will be transfered to server (2) on flash drive. On server (2) there will be HTTP/FTP sever to downloaded files.

In other words,
1) How to download all apt repository data on Windows from apt get repository?
2) How to setup apt repository on Windows with just downloaded from another computer files?

Comment: Maybe duplicate from: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/217667/host-a-debian-repository-on-a-windows-web-ftp-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think same steps as Linux machines,

Install HTTP or FTP server (I would use Apache HTTPD), and do a rsync from official mirrors.

Regards